# Saved FabricJS don't store lockScalingX

Tags: json, canvas, save, store, fabricjs

After a few test I finally saved a fabric.canvas to a MySQL database, the problem is that I don't want that the images in the canvas can be resized, I only need the rotation. Unfortunately the json stored doesn't store the lockScalingX and lockScalingY properties of the fabric.Image object and when I retrieve the fabric.canvas I can resize the image.

Is there any way to avoid this?

I use the function

```
var jsonCanvas = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessObject());
```

to store the json to a database using php
And I retrive the stored json using

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(data);
```

To see what I'm talking about see this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/lpccoder/YX9Wf/1/
I set the oImg.lockScalingX = oImg.lockScalingY = true; before to add to canvas to avoid resizing.
The button Save, saves the canvas but when I load it (using Load button) I can resize the image.

Well as I don't received any answer for this, I'm trying to set the lockScalingX and lockScalingY after load the canvas, but some strange behaviour happens when I use the forEach method. I mean, I need to put an alert before the forEach to get this working, if I don't put this alert the forEach loop doesn't work. To clarify this you can see and compare this two fiddles:

Working one -> jsfiddle.net/lpccoder/hGPCG/

Non working one -> jsfiddle.net/lpccoder/Vv4AW/

I'm new on javascript coding, maybe it's a newbie question, but I think that's a very strange behaviour... Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rodrigo Pandini who answer this question at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/rGX8F93TeGE

The solution is to use the callback function to set the properties manually:

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonCanvas, function(){
  var objects = canvas.getObjects();
  // Trying to set the property after load JSON
  //alert('Objects: ' + objects);
  objects.forEach(function(o) {
    o.lockScalingX = o.lockScalingY = true;
  });
  canvas.renderAll(); 
});
```

Because as far as I know the json doesn't store this properties.
You can check the final solution at -> http://jsfiddle.net/lpccoder/Vv4AW/1/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Remember to accept your answer later for future visitors.